# Cannot Read Property label of Undefined in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a weird problem with onCHangeDropDown of react. The following is the PtSelect and PTInput Code of React.
So let me explain what is happening the first PtSelect contains values from 0 to 5 with an interval of 0.25 between each value the second PtSelect contains values from 0 to 4 with the same interval between the values. The onChangeSRnRqiDropdown code contains a formula which is being calculated based on the values selected from the first and second PtSelect and it will appear on the PtInput. When I select the value above 4 from the first PtSelect it throws an error of Cannot Read property 'label' of undefined. However, the same code works perfectly fine if I select any value from less than 4. The problem happens if I try to go above value 4. 
Any help is really appreciated. Thanks. 
The below is the full code of the component as requested.

```
    <PtSelect options={RQITypeOptions} onChange={this.onChangeSRnRqiDropdown} disabled={this.props.disabled} name="RQIOver" defaultVal={this.state.RQIOver}/>
    <PtSelect options={SRTypeOptions} onChange={this.onChangeSRnRqiDropdown} disabled={this.props.disabled} defaultVal={this.state.SROver} name="SROver" />
    <PtInputConditionTab disabled whichInput="secondttb" inputType="number" name="PQIOver" placeholder="override" value={this.state.PQIOver == null ? '' : this.state.PQIOver} onChange={this.onInputChange} />

    onChangeSRnRqiDropdown = (e) => {
        const { target } = e;
        const { name, value } = target;
        this.props.triggerNeedSave();
        this.setState({ [name]: parseInt(value) }, () =>
        {
            const { RQITypeOptions, SRTypeOptions, } = DropdownLib.getDropdowns().CSF_Condition;

            this.setState({ PQIOver: (this.state.SROver !== 0 && this.state.RQIOver !=

= 0) ? Math.sqrt(RQITypeOptions[this.state.SROver].label * SRTypeOptions[this.state.RQIOver].label).toFixed(2) : null });
    });


}
```

Comment: Please post the entire React component. We have no idea what your props or your state is supposed to look like, or what `triggerNeededSave()` does. I'm guessing the source of the bug is in one of these functions you are calling from within `onChangeSRnRqiDropdown()`. But too much context is missing to tell.

Comment: Also, show us the error log.

Comment: I have posted the whole code along with the error log as requested. Thanks

Comment: Whoever asked for all the code was mistaken: StackOverflow questions should include the least code necessary

Comment: That what I did previously when you first commented about you cud have some private jet for every debugging. And after reading that I was also hoping how some one can figure out which particular code I am talking about. So what do you suggest, shall I remove the extra codes?   @GeorgeJempty

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What options do you have in `options={RQITypeOptions}`?

Also whats in your `this.state`

Answer (score 0):

In the `this.state` inside `Math.sqrt` `RQITypeOptions` and `SRTypeOptions` needs to be swapped. Because the problem was the label could not found as the key doesn't exists. 
So the code will be following:

```
this.setState({ PQIOver: (this.state.SROver !== 0 && this.state.RQIOver !== 0) ? Math.sqrt(SRTypeOptions[this.state.SROver].label * RQITypeOptions[this.state.RQIOver].label).toFixed(2) : null });
```